# What is the effect of diet on sleep allowances?

Tags: diet, sleep

This website http://www.theminimalists.com/diet/ claims that "...because of diet and exercise, I need less sleep than I used to. Most mornings I wake around 3:30 a.m., after five or six hours of sleep". According to https://sleepfoundation.org/press-release/national-sleep-foundation-recommends-new-sleep-times (admittedly, a more reputable source on matters of health) they recommend that "Adults (26-64)" sleep "7-9 hours" per night. I understand that this applies to the average adult, so it seems that the first source could be true. So this made me wonder, **what effect (if any) does diet have on someone's sleep?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exercise can improve sleep quality, as demonstrated for instance [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20113919), so maybe this improved quality reduces the needed quantity of sleep. It has been claimed that the practice of yoga reduces sleep needs, and long-term yoga practice has been [linked to better sleep quality](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19482233). 
As for diet and sleep, there are indeed correlations, but these may vary and it seems the impact could go both ways. In particular, sleep deprivation has been linked to [increased caloric intake](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27804960). Closer to your question, [a study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27633109) on the effects of diet on sleep quality has shown evidence of the impact of certain foods on sleep quality, but concludes on the necessity of more studies on the subject.